# How to integrate cdn of bootstrap using webpack only in production mode

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-3

Hi i am using htmlwebpackextract plugin.here is my config code

```
new HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin(
            {
            externals: [
                {
                    module: 'jquery',
                    entry:'https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js',
                    global: 'jQuery'
                },
                {
                    module: 'bootstrap',
                    entry: {
                        path: 'https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                        type: 'css'
                    },
                    append: true,
                }
            ],
            enabled:isProd,
            }

        )
```

It gives some error as cannot read property 'var'of null.In index.js require('bootstrap') is there

Comment: Post the exact error, not a barely comprehensible paraphrase of it.

Comment: I am able to execute jquery as cdn link to html file inproduction mode.But when i use same method for bootstrap it is shows error as 'var'of null.In index.js

Comment: Hi, have you find the solution? I hit the same problem.

Comment: Yes.I am using cdn for both production and development mode now. @Qiulang

Comment: So how did you fix the webpack error

Comment: Can you say the error which you got?

Comment: Same as yours, "cannot read property 'var'of null.In index.js require('bootstrap') "

Comment: Removed enabled:isProd from my code it worked for me.

Comment: https://github.com/Rajcbe/Webpack-sample-project .see this sample webpack project for more info.It has dev and prod mode setup with srcset loader for 2x 3x image reduction @Qiulang